# What is the fastest way to transfer data from SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have a Database that is corrupted, backup and restore does not work, the table contains 180 million records with a total size of 1TB.

I need to copy the data from the table to another, but it is very slow because the tables contain 3 columns with VARCHAR, I've already tried Linked Server, Bulk copy, BCP and SSIS, but they are all taking a long time, to copy 50 million records It's taking 30 hours.

I did the test without the 3 VARCHAR(MAX) columns and it runs very fast.

```
  

CREATE TABLE [dbo].TABLE_01
(
    Column_1 [bigint] NOT NULL,
    Column_2 [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    Column_3 [datetime] NOT NULL,
    Column_4 [varchar](39) NULL,
    Column_5 [int] NULL,
    Column_6 [varchar](100) NULL,
    Column_7 [varchar](100) NULL,
    Column_8 [int] NULL,
    Column_9 [varchar](30) NULL,
    Column_10 [int] NULL,
    Column_11 [varchar](100) NULL,
    Column_12 [varchar](100) NULL,
    Column_13 [int] NULL,
    Column_14 [varchar](30) NULL,
    Column_15 [int] NULL,
    Column_16 [varchar](30) NULL,
    Column_17 [varchar](250) NULL,
    Column_18 [int] NULL,
    Column_19 [varchar](30) NULL,
    Column_20 [varchar](250) NULL,
    Column_21 [varchar](max) NULL,
    Column_22 [varchar](max) NULL,
    Column_23 [varchar](max) NULL
)
```

Is there another way to do this procedure faster?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to copy them off the server? Or would it be ok to copy them to another database on the same server?

Comment: Using SSIS package https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/sql-server-integration-services?view=sql-server-ver16
Using Nifi
Using ODBC connection, like C# apps, middle ware or other solution

Comment: @J.D. If it's faster, it could be on the same server.

Comment: It absolutely is faster to not move data across servers.

Comment: And what procedure do you suggest? any software?
I have already done this test with Bulk copy, BCP and SSIS, but it is very slow

Comment: if on the same server, try `select * into targettable from sourcetable`. `select.. into` into is minimally logged so it shouldn't blow out your transaction log

Comment: Fastest is going to be on the same instance, but between two databases stored on different drives.

Comment: What are the signs of corruption that you see? With a different drive, as @xedni says, select into should be quickest, but you do have to read & write a 1TB table to a different db. You probably want to chunk that so you can check progress & restart if interrupted.